# HASH Algorithm for 8 bits MCU

Tags: hash, md5, sha-1, lightweight

I need to implement the HASH algorithm (MD5 & SHA-1) on an 8 bit MCU. I hear it can only be implemented on 32bit and sometimes 16bits MCU. Is that possible? I will appreciate link where possible. A program in C language most preferred.

Comment: In general, most algorithms can be implemented on any kind of computer, it is just more or less complicated. Impossible it is only when they use more memory (or other resources) than available.

Answer (score 2):

Someone answered it in another "exchange" site: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1830/md5-implementation-for-microcontroller

There you have links to C implementations, etc.

And yes, it's possible to implement MD5 and SHA1 in 8bits, you'll just have to worki with 16 (or 32) bits operations, not that hard...